# Why Firebase works only first time I open the app?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To store and retrieve data about my users in my app I'm using Firebase Realtime Database.
To read data I do the following code. I tried to put it in OnCreate or OnStart or in OnRestart, nothing works.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DATABASE_NAME/europe-west1/firebasedatabase/app/");
mDatabase.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        loggedUser = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.e("onDataChange Oncancelled",error.toString());
    }
});
```

but this only works the first time. The call to **getValue** returns null.
Neither onDataChange nor onCancelled are triggered, and I have an active internet connection on my device.
How can I fix this?

Comment: So you say that onDataChange nor onCancelled are triggered, right? Are you sure you have an active internet connection on the device? Besides that, what is the location of your database and how did define `mDatabase`? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i have internet connection and the internet permission in my manifest

Comment: Thanks. Cleaning up some comments to allow folks to focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you initialize `mDatabase` here is wrong:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DATABASE_NAME/europe-west1/firebasedatabase/app/");
```

You have to pass the database URL to `getInstance`, not to `getReference`. So:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://DATABASE_NAME.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference();
```

Be sure to copy/paste the URL exactly as is into the `getInstance` call.